# Could I use Select with condition on any column other than First (Last)?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I often deal with huge tables of various functions of randomly generated values for my research. Sometimes there's need to only keep rows which satisfy a specific condition. This is easy with `Select` if the condition is on the `First` column; I use something like this:

```
tab = Table[{τ, V*amod, u, ph} /. {u -> (RandomReal[{0, 3}])*
                  Exp[I*RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]]} // N, {i, 1, 200}]

pos = Table[{Select[tab, Im[First[#]] > 0 &][[j, 1]], tab[[j, 2]], tab[[j, 3]], 
              tab[[j, 4]]}, {j, Length[Select[tab, Im[First[#]] > 0 &][[All, 1]]]}]
```

Let's not get into the details of what's what in the main table `tab` here please, because that's not important at all. The focus is the position of entries in the table. The only thing necessary to know is that they're all functions of the randomly generated `u`.

So my question is, what if I want to impose a condition on a column where I can't use the command `First` (or `Last`)? Like if my table now is

```
alltab = Table[{P, amod, Im[τ], u, V} /. {m -> 1, b -> -4} /. 
              {u ->(RandomReal[{0, 3}])*Exp[I*RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]]} // N, {i, 1, 2500}]
```

and I want to impose a condition on `Im[τ]` again, how should I rewrite the `Select` ? I've tried several different ways and it hasn't worked. Namely,

```
Table[{Select[alltab[[j]], Im[#3] > 0 &][[j, 6]], alltab[[j, 4]]}, {j, 1000}]
```

or

```
Table[{Select[alltab[[j, 3]], Im[#] > 0 &], alltab[[j, 4]]}, {j, 1000}]
```

or

```
Table[{Select[alltab, Im[[[j, 3]][#]] > 0 &], alltab[[j, 4]]}, {j, 1000}]
```

and a few other ways. I wanna see if there is any other way around this other than manually changing the position of coulumns. The use of `Select` is not necessary either; I'm always open to better ways to write code.

Comment: Just select from alltab (or whatever subset of it), with condition `#[[3]]...` or `Part[#,3]...`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: nope, it was as simple as that @ciao . It took me longer to type this question than to fix it. Excuse me while I go throw myself down from a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, the data that you generated called `tab` has a real and imaginary component in column 3.

```
tab = Table[{τ, V*amod, u, ph}
    /. {u -> (RandomReal[{0, 3}])*Exp[I*RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]]} // N, 
    {i, 1, 200}]
```

In order to select the rows that have the imaginary component of the third column that are greater than zero you can use:

```
Select[tab, Im[#[[3]]] > 0 &];
```

If you want to get the positions you could try:

```
Position[tab, elem_ /; Im[elem[[3]]] > 0, {1}];
```